# Read data from a file line by line

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am currently open a file and show it on a message box.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
    file.FileName = "";
    file.Title = "Open A Text document.";
    file.Filter = "(*.gc)|*.gc|(*.etf)|*.etf|(*.txt)|*.txt|(*.GC)|*.GC|(*.tap)|*.tap";
    DialogResult result = file.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader OpenFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(file.FileName);
        textBox1.Text = OpenFile.ReadToEnd();
        OpenFile.Close();


    }

    if (file.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        OpenFile(file.FileName);
    }
```

But I need to read the file line by line and show it on a message box. Is there a way to change this code.

Comment: are you saying to want to display a separate message box for each line in the file?

Comment: use ReadLine() instead of ReadToEnd

Comment: I want to show it in the same message box

Comment: @Sthn So you want to display the entire file in a single message box? Have you tried `MessageBox.Show(OpenFile.ReadToEnd());`?

Comment: @Sthn than why do you need to read it line by line

Comment: @Sam I am I need to send the content of the file to a Micro-Controller line by line that is why I need to read line by line

Answer (score 2):

There is a [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) method that returns an IEnumerable so you can do:

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("myfile.txt")){
   //Do stuff with line
}
```

Comment: +1 Din't know about ReadLines which returns IEnumerable

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - There were a lot of subtle API improvements all over in .Net 4.0 IEnumerable friendly IO was one of them that was a God Send for LINQ.

Comment: Yep, I know some (like Directory.EnumerateFiles) but this is first time I see ReadLines :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - All the Async stuff in 4.5 is amazeballs as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [StreamReader.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what the [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) method is for

```
while (OpenFile.Peek() >= 0) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(OpenFile.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: how to use this if I want to use a textBox instead of a message box

Comment: Use `textBox.Text += OpenFile.ReadLine()` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the `OpenFile.ReadLine()` method?

---

or, for a more radical approach

```
string[] lines = OpenFile.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to read all lines from file is [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) method (internally it uses `StreamReader`):

```
foreach(string line File.ReadAllLines(fileName))
    MessageBox.Show(line);
```